# How to move the view of a zoomed picture with arrow keys?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, image-viewers

I use Image Viewer. Whenever I want to move the view on a zoomed picture, it takes me to the next picture and that is so annoying for me. Is there any hotkey or some setting that I am unaware of?

Is there any software for image viewing that does this task?

I need to be able to move a zoomed picture using arrow keys (Keyboard), without the use of the mouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Image Viewer you can do this by holding down the <kbd>ALT</kbd> key when using the arrow keys.

See the program help screen:

[image: shortcut keys list]